# how to have landscape and portrait pages in one document in web using css, js,

Tags: javascript, css

I want to print page 1 in portrait and page 2 in landscape that both are in one web page but

```
@page {size: landscape}
```

in css makes whole document(web page) printable pages landscape.
how can customize it for every page?(my purpose of the page here is page in print)

we can have first page landscape and other pages portrait with

```
@page:first {
    size: landscape;
}
```

but it works only for first page. How to work for other pages like this(ex: First page portrait and other pages landscape)?

Comment: Are the different pages implemented as different divs (or sections)? Then you could do something like keep the document as portrait, but rotate the second div 90deg.

Comment: @Mr Lister : yes, I rotated the section(in my case, the div containing a table), but the problem is the table or div size does not fix to page size.